# Can't map over constructed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Having some trouble mapping over this array to create elements. What I'm doing is fairly simple. I'm querying my database which returns and title and a URL. I then send that URL out to fetch the html from a website. I go through that response and pull out a bunch of json objects. Those objects are pushed to an array. Then I want to map through that array to post images to my screen. What I have read online is that you can't map over a constructed array. But if I'm not mistaken I'm doing that once and it works fine. But when it comes to pulling the variables from the array and using it to produce the img it doesn't work.

```
class Scraper extends Component {

         arraystuff = [];

         handleData = (data) => {
             data.allSearches.map((datum) => {
             // This is constructing the results array.
             this.results.push({ title: datum.title, url: datum.url });
             });

             // Now I'm mapping over results without issue
             this.results.map(async (post) => {
             await fetch(
             `http://localhost:4100/scrape/${encodeURIComponent(post.url)}`
             )
             .then((res) => res.json())

             // Now I am constructing the arraystuff array. I cannot map over this in the render
             .then((res) => res.map((result) => this.arraystuff.push(result)));
             });
         };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Query query={ALL_SEARCHES_QUERY}>
          {({ error, loading, data }) => {
            if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            this.handleData(data);
            return null;
          }}
        </Query>
        <div>
          {this.arraystuff.map((search) => {
            // This is what isn't working
            <img
              src={`http:${search.photo}`}
              alt={search.id}
              key={search.id}
            />;
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Scraper;
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Doesn't seem like it should be that difficult. Driving me nuts

Comment: If you have dynamic data that needs to be rendered it should be in the state. Just pushing to a member variable won't cause a re-render, so nothing's gonna show.

Comment: I had considered that, but the data is fetched and loaded when the page load. If I set it to state it’ll do a re-render loop won’t it?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to refactor it so that you fetch all the things you need, then call one `setState` at the end to add them all to the state in one go. That way there's only one re-render. You can do something like awaiting a `Promise.all` to fetch all the required data.

Comment: doesnt look like your anonymous arrow function is being called. {({ error, loading, data }) => {
            if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            this.handleData(data);
            return null;
          }} can you confirm?

Comment: Anonymous function is indeed running. Did some refactoring and made some progress. I'll finish it up in the morning. Thank you very much for the help.